# Investigate uniqueness of the following differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

This is Problem 1.13 from Teschl's book (ODEs and Dynamical Systems). The equation is as follows:

$$
x' =
\begin{cases}
-t\sqrt{|x|}, &\text{ if } x \ge 0\\
t\sqrt{|x|}, &\text{ if } x \le 0.
\end{cases}
$$

It asks to show that the initial value problem $x(0) = x_0$ has unique global solution for every $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. There is a hint saying that if $x(t)$ is a solution so is $-x(t)$ and $x(-t)$, so it suffices to consider $x_0 \ge 0$ and $t \ge 0$. For $x_0 > 0$, I managed to find the solution

$$
x(t) =
\begin{cases}
(\sqrt{x_0} - \frac{1}{4}t^2)^2, &\text{ if } |t| \le 2x_0^{1/4}\\
0, &\text{ otherwise. }
\end{cases} 
$$

It is easy to see that this is a solution by using the Mean Value Theorem when calculating $x'(t)$ for $t = \pm 2x_0^{1/4}$, because $x$ is continuous at these points and $x'(\theta) \to 0$ as $\theta \to t$. For $x_0 = 0$ the obvious solution is $x(t) = 0$ for all $t$. The problem is that I do not know how to show these solutions are unique.

If $x$ is a is solution and $x_0 > 0$, then by continuity there is an open interval $(t_1, t_2)$ containing $0$ where $x(t)$ is positive, and so it makes sense to write

$$
-s = \frac{x'(s)}{\sqrt{x(s)}},
$$

for $s \in (t_1, t_2)$, and to integrate both sides

\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{2}t^2 = \int_{0}^t -s\ ds = \int_0^t \frac{x'(s)}{\sqrt{x(s)}}\ ds = 2(\sqrt{x(t)} - \sqrt{x(0)}).
\end{align}

This yields $x(t) = (\sqrt{x_0} - \frac{1}{4}t^2)^2$ for $t \in (t_1, t_2)$. Assuming that $(t_1, t_2)$ is a maximal interval where $x(t)$ is positive, and since $(t_1, t_2) \subseteq (-2x_0^{1/4}, 2x_0^{1/4})$, we see by continuity of $x$ that $x(t_1) = x(t_2) = 0$ and thus $(t_1, t_2) = (-2x_0^{1/4}, 2x_0^{1/4})$. How do I show that $x(t) = 0$ when $t$ is not in this interval? I suspect the same technique in this last step can be used to show that $x(t) = 0$ when $x_0 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've done it. Suppose first $x_0 = 0$ and let $x(t)$ be a solution. Assume by contradiction that $x(t) > 0$ for some $t > 0$ and set
$$
d = \inf\{a < t: x(s) > 0 \text{ for every } s \in (a, t) \}.
$$
By continuity $d$ is well defined, $0 \le d < t$ and $x(d) = 0$. By the Mean Value Theorem, we see that
$$
x(t) = x(t) - x(d) = x'(\theta)(t - d),
$$
for some $\theta \in (d, t)$, so
$$
x(t) = -\theta\sqrt{|x(\theta)|}(t - d) \le 0
$$
which is a contradiction. If $x(t) < 0$ the proof should be analogous and we can do the same thing to finish what I wrote above for the case $x_0 > 0$.

Comment: Yes, this **part** is O.K. I would only define $d$ as the supremum of the set of those $a<t$ such that $x(a)=0$ (easier to show it is nonempty). Remember that you should also show that we have uniqueness at each point where the value of the solution is nonzero, and that any solution is global. Can you do that?

Comment: @user539887 What do you mean by "uniqueness at each point where the value of the solution is nonzero"? I have shown it is unique for every choice of $x_0$, isn't that all there is to it?

Comment: You showed only that the solution cannot branch at a point where its value is $0$. At other points it cannot branch, either, but here one needs to use, for example, the local Lipschitz continuity at such a point. Or, alternatively, you can argue that your arguments in the last paragraph of your question show that the obtained formula is the only possible.

Answer (score 0):

To prove uniqueness, let's assume two solutions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, $x(0)=y(0)=x_0>0$. Let $u=x-y$ with $u(0)=u_0=0$. We subtract the equations for $x$ and $y$ and obtain 
$$
u'(t)=-t\frac{u}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}},
$$
which yields 
$$
u(t)=u_0 \exp\left(-\int_0^t \frac{s}{\sqrt{x(s)}+\sqrt{y(s)}}ds\right).
$$
Since $u_0=0$, then $u\equiv0$.